# The quotient of a scheme by a proper equivalence relation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, ct.category-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme and $R$ be a proper equivalence relation on $X$.

What can be said about the geometric structure of the quotient $X/R$? Is it representable by a stack, for example?

Comment: What sort of stack are you after? 

Comment: any, I only wanted to now what looks like such an object.

Comment: You should better make your question a bit more precise, because the possible answers depend on the sense you give to the quotient (is it a fibered category ? an fppf sheaf ?).

Comment: I make the quotient as a sheaf.

Comment: If you consider the sheaf quotient, then being representable by an algebraic stack is nothing more than being representable by an algebraic space (a scheme-like thing, really). Anyway in order to have theorems you need to assume at least that the equivalence relation is flat. The best classical result close to what you are asking is Thm. 6.1 in Grothendieck's Bourbaki talk 212.